# help with dns name conflict vpn and docker

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, iptables, docker

I need to access an url via VPN,  (estrelaoriente.com)
but seems it is conflicting with an docker route (docker.amazee.io):

~$ ping estrelaoriente.com
PING estrelaoriente.com.docker.amazee.io (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms

if I ping this server ip it connects ok,
I have already deleted all docker images, flushed iptables, flushed dns, even removed full docker instalation, but cant find where this route is defined.

any help apreciated, thanks

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: version 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: I could be wrong but I think you need to research netplan.  Here's the website https://netplan.io/.  I would also search ubuntu sites/forums for netplan/DNS issues/configurations.  If you run into issues edit your question and provide specific details of what you are seeing.